# Difference between Programmable Messaging API and Conversational API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

In Twilio, Both of the APIs are essentially made for programmable messaging, then what exactly is the difference?

Both of the API's can be used for A2P messaging, integrating with Bots, extending communication use cases.
[Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/messaging/conversations-api) is said to have the advantage of integrating multiple channels into one application, but so can [messaging APIs](https://www.twilio.com/messaging/programmable-messaging-api). If both are not mutually exclusive, the distinction is not very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Conversations API** is used for **1 to 1** (or multi) communication between users: send and reply.
This is more suitable for customer support and customer relations.

**Programmable Messaging API** is used for **software to user** communication: alerts and notifications.
This is suitable for appointment remainders, alerts, delivery notifications and sending temporary web tokens. Also, it is made for a larger scale than Conversations APIs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/6447529/uri-loya!